# If $h$ is self-adjoint then $e^{ih}$ is unitary

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

> Let $A$ be a unital C*-algebra. If $h \in A$ is self adjoint, then $e^{ih}$ is unitary.

This proof is in a lecture note, which I am not able to understand. They prove it in the following way:

For any $f \in \mathcal{C}(\mathrm{sp}(h))$, $f(h)^* =\bar{f}(h) =f^{-1}(h)$.

I do not understand where the equality follow from. Why is $f$ invertible, and what if $f$ has zero in its range?

**Edit**: By $e^{ih}$ I mean the element in $A$ we get by functional calculas, $C^*(1,h) \cong \mathcal{C}(sp(h))$. For $e^{ix} \in \mathcal{C}(sp(h))$ we get an element $e^{ih} \in C^*(1,h) \subseteq A$.

Answer (score 5):

That's not true in general, but it is if you consider $f(t)=e^{it}$. For this particular $f$ you have $\bar f=f^{-1}$.

A proof involving less theory is to use that the adjoint operation is continuous: then
$$
(e^{ih})^*=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{i^k h^k}{k!}\right)^*
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-i)^k h^k}{k!}=e^{-ih}.
$$
Then use that $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$ when $ab=ba$ to get 
$$
e^{ih}e^{-ih}=e^{ih-ih}=I. 
$$

Comment: $\bar f=f^{-1}$ and $e^{ih}$ are slightly ambiguous, with $f(h) = \exp(ih)$, in general $f(h)^{-1} = f(-h)$ and when $h = h^*$ then $f(h)^* = \exp((ih)^*) = f(-h)$

Comment: @Argerami In infinite sum can we distribute the * on each elemnt?

Comment: The adjoint is continuous, so yes.